# Update ng-repeat value with ng-model

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="board in allBoards track by $index" ng-model="board">
<a href="#" class="success button" ng-click="UpdateBoards(board);">&#10004;</a>
```

What I am trying to do is modifying board name with UpdateBoards(). But I click the button, values of the input are not passed to UpdateBoards, what should I change? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us UpdateBoards()? I do not immediately see any reason why that wouldn't pass your board obj.

Comment: I just use  console.log(board) to check wther the value is passed. But it's undefined. Somehow, i figure out how to solve it: `<input type="text" ng-repeat="(i, board) in boards track by $index" value="{{board}}" ng-model="boards[i]"  ng-change="UpdateBoards(boards);">`

Answer (score 0):

So for I understand your problem try following:

```
<div ng-repeat="board in allBoards track by $index">
      <input type="text" ng-model="board">
      <a href="#" class="success button" ng-click="UpdateBoards(board);">&#10004;</a>
</div>
```

By wrapping `ng-repeat` in `div` and calling each `input and a href tag` inside `div`, hope it will help you.